# How to open webapp directly in safari browser?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, safari

I have website and I added to home screen in my iPhone but when I click on some link of my website it open in safari browser and some open inside the webapp.

Is it possible when I click on my web app in iPhone which I saved by add to home screen it directly open website on safari browser directly not in web app ?

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html):

> Set the apple-mobile-web-app-capable meta tag to yes to turn on standalone mode. For example, the following HTML displays web content using standalone mode.
>
> `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no">`
>
> You can determine whether a webpage is displaying in standalone mode using the window.navigator.standalone read-only Boolean JavaScript property. For more on standalone mode, see apple-mobile-web-app-capable.

Comment: I added this but still opening in web app.You can check here in source code and can check to add to home screen https://timesharefriends.com

Comment: @NiteshSharma sorry, I misunderstood you. If you want it to open in safari, seems like you should specify this property as `no`